# removing the comment line from text file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command

I have a text file with the following text in it.

```
/* a comment line in a C program */
 printf("It is /* NOT a comment line */\n");
 x = 5; /* This is an assignment, not a comment line */
 [TAB][SPACE] /* another empty comment line here */
 /* another weird line, but not a comment line */ y = 0;
```

I want to remove the lines with starts with `/*` and ends with `*/` only using linux commands.

I wrote the following code to do so.

```
egrep "^/*.+*/$" small.txt
```

I saved the text in my `small.txt` file.

But it outputs all lines which only ends with `*/`.

The output is as under.

```
/* a comment line in a C program */
 x = 5; /* This is an assignment, not a comment line */
 [TAB][SPACE] /* another empty comment line here */
```

My desired output is

```
/* a comment line in a C program */
```

Comment: What about comments spanning several lines?

Comment: Remove the spacing and tabs first and replace the file.

Comment: ??? Replace the FILE? What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `sed` to remove commented line:

```
sed '\~^/\*.*\*/$~d' file.c
```

Or using `grep`:

```
grep -v '^/\*.*\*/$' file.c
```

```
 printf("It is /* NOT a comment line */\n");
 x = 5; /* This is an assignment, not a comment line */
 [TAB][SPACE] /* another empty comment line here */
 /* another weird line, but not a comment line */ y = 0;
```

To print only matching line:

```
sed '\~^/\*.*\*/$~!d' file.c
```

or using `grep`:

```
grep '^/\*.*\*/$' file.c
```

```
/* a comment line in a C program */
```

Answer (score 0):

So first we will remove the spaces and tabs as follows.

```
sed "s/^[ \t]*//" -i small.txt
```

This will replace the **small.txt** with the one in which the leading spaces and tabs are removed.

The we will run the following command to extract the comments.

```
grep  '^/\*.*\*/$' small.txt
```